# Is there a way to connect to a GIT HTTPS site using a smart card on macOS?

Tags: git, macos, bitbucket, smartcard, cac

I have a bitbucket site that supports smart cards only. It's operational and using Safari I can login using a smart card and PIN. I cannot use SSH for this instance.

Does anyone know of a client or way to use Git in a terminal command that would support a smart card?

Any git clone attempts 403 fail due to not passing a valid certificate to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Git is generally designed to operate on certificates in files.  However, if you're using HTTPS and your Git is built against Apple's Secure Transport library, then you can set `http.sslCert` to a handle to a certificate in the keychain, as documented in the [libcurl documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLCERT.html).  If you're using a version built against OpenSSL or GnuTLS, then no, this isn't supported.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to contact your server administrator about providing a functional approach, such as using SSH, or providing suitable documentation about how to appropriately use the server.